# Where can I download the deb installer of MyUnity?

Tags: 12.04, installation, deb, myunity

I'm an Ubuntu 12.04 complete offline user.

I need MyUnity tool to change the fonts of Ubuntu.

Can anyone give me the offline installer?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the link:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/myunity/myunity_3.1.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
This is for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS i386